# How do I map two records that belong to the same table, on SQL Server?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using Sql Server,EF and MVC
I have a few tables like

```
 Product
  Id          (int,PK)
  Supplier    (int,FK)
  ProductName (varchar)
```

I want to map Multiple Products so when i query a product can find equivalent product of other Suppliers.

I am trying to add another table for map.

```
  ProductMap
     ProductId      (int)
     Supplier       (int)
     OtherProductId (int)
```

But This way is hard to query. So is there any better way ?

Comment: Your question is lacking a very important piece, enough details to even guess at an answer.

Comment: Sorry for being vague,

Comment: There is three Prodcts and Two Supplier   <br/> 
P1=Apple,  <br/> 
P2=Banana,  <br/>
P3=Orange  <br/>
  <br/>
S1 Selling (id=1-Apple,id=3-Banana       )  <br/>
S2 Selling (id=2-Apple,id=4-Banana,Orange)  <br/>
  <br/>
I want to map Apples to Apples for every Supplier  <br/>
so i can see Total Count,Sell ext by Apple Kind  <br/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't you just query it like this?:

```
SELECT  p.Id ,
        p.Supplier ,
        p.ProductName ,
        pm.Supplier ,
        pm.OtherProductId
FROM    Product p
        INNER JOIN ProductMap pm ON p.ID = pm.ProductId
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty vague, but I think I know what you're after.

If your "products" are identical things that can be purchased from multiple suppliers, then you only need to store each product once. As a class, that looks like this:

```
class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public List<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
}
```

As SQL tables, that would look like this:

```
Product                    
    ProductId       (int)
    ProductName     (varchar)

ProductSupplier
    ProductId       (int)
    SupplierId      (int)

Supplier
    SupplierId      (int)
    SupplierName    (varchar)
```

So now you have a one-to-many relationship from products to suppliers who have that product, and because you're using Entity Framework, your query is then like this in C#:

```
var suppliers = myDbContext.Products
                    .Single(p => p.ProductName == "product")
                    .Suppliers.ToList();
```

and that gives you a list of everyone who supplies that product. If different suppliers have different prices, then just add a `Price` column to the `ProductSupplier` table to store the price that this supplier sells this product at.

If your "products" are not 100% identical, and you're looking for similar things sold by other people, then you want a similar thing, but instead you have product "categories" (or "types" or whatever you want to call them) that you use to store things that are considered equivalent. From there, your `Product` would have a `ProductCategoryId` foreign key, so for a given product, you'd look up its category to find all equivalent items. As a class, that looks like this:

```
class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

As SQL tables, that would something look like this:

```
Product                    
    ProductId       (int)
    ProductName     (varchar)
    CategoryId      (int)
    SupplierId      (int)

ProductCategory
    Id              (int)
    Description     (varchar)

Supplier
    SupplierId      (int)
```

Again, EF makes the query pretty straightforward:

```
var similarProducts = myDbContext.Products
                    .Single(p => p.ProductName == product")
                    .Category.Products.ToList();
```